# Update date for realm entries

Tags: ios, realm

Does Realm entries contain the date of which they were updated?
If not, is there a best practice to add this kind of information?

Thanks

Comment: No, but you can add a date field for it and update the field value when you update the object. Which platform?

Comment: Thanks. RealmSwift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not there by default, but it's easy to add. Just add an `updated` property to your Realm class like this:

```
import RealmSwift

class YourThing: Object {
  dynamic var updated = Date()    
}
```

And every time you do a write transaction with an object from that class, just update it with the current date:

```
do{
  try realm.write {
    thingObject.updated = Date()
  }
}catch let error{
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Good luck. :)